# Add Custom Prefix on URL on mybb

Tags: javascript, php

Please someone help me to add Custom Prefix on URL. Am using mybb forum.
I have list of referral code from various site in refer.php
So, I would like to add default custom prefix on every outbound url (default) as **http://store.com/forums/refer.php?url=**

Example if any one shared url of ebay on my forum it want to redirect as http://store.com/forums/refer.php?url=http://www.ebay.com

Comment: Typical Stack Overflow questions address a specific issues, not a how-to type scenario. Posting what you've done and the resulting error would point your question in the right direction.

Comment: Am not well experience in this field. Simply I would like to add custom (default) prefix on every url in my forum as following http://store.com/forums/refer.php?url=

There is lots of plugins on wordpress... But I would like to know how can I change the url in mybb